# Material thickness for UL94 compatible overmolds?

Tags: enclosure

I would like to overmold a PCBA which needs to meet UL 94V-0 requirements. For previous shell-like enclosures we would just keep everything above the minimal approved thickness specified in the material's datasheet, but I assume overmolded parts don't need the full minimal thickness covering everything due to the PCBA itself already being UL 94V-0.

Is there a good rule of thumb for how thick the overmolded layer of plastic should be in order to meet UL 94, based on the minimal approved thickness?

Comment: UL94V-O is a flammability specification. not an electrical one. Put as much or as little of the goo as you like as long as it is self-extinguishing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that it is about flammability. My concern is whether a thin layer of goo might be more (too much) flammable than a thick one. Maybe that doesn't make any sense.